# Substract 1 month to update table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to update all the `issuedat` (date field) to be less than one month from the column `paidat` (date field)

ex:

```
if paidat = 01/02/2011 then issuedat should = 01/01/2011

UPDATE invoices SET invoices.issuedat = ????
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE invoices SET invoices.issuedat = dateadd(MM,-1,paidat)
```

Comment: Thanks ... perfect. should be (MM,-1,paidat) but I get it.

Comment: Sorry, read your question too fast. I will update my answer. Interestingly enough, @Magnus made the same mistake :)